# How to Set Dropdown selected

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I want to set dropdownlist selected when the value is match but it always last option get selected EUR, please help me how will i do this, here is my dropdownlist code ...

```
           <select class="select" name="TicketCurrency">
                <option selected="@(ticketDetails != null ? ticketDetails.TicketCurrency == "INR" ? "selected" : "" : "")">
                    INR</option>
                <option selected="@(ticketDetails != null ? ticketDetails.TicketCurrency == "USD" ? "selected" : "" : "")">
                    USD</option>
                <option selected="@(ticketDetails != null ? ticketDetails.TicketCurrency == "EUR" ? "selected" : "" : "")">
                    EUR</option>
            </select>
```

Comment: Your setting the `selected` attribute in all options. `selected` or `selected=""` or `selected="selected"` all mean that the option is selected. You tagged this MVC so learn to use the html helper methods which do all this for you.

Comment: could you tell me what will write, i mean code

Comment: ok i did this using:  <option @(ticketDetails != null ? ticketDetails.TicketCurrency == "INR" ? "selected" : "" : "")>
                        INR</option>

Comment: Why use MVC is your going to write bad html like this.

Answer (score 2):

@Stephen is correct, `selected or selected="" or selected="selected"` all are making option to get selected and you are able to see the last one as selected.

Basically, you are messing up with HTML code! If you are using MVC why not take great advantage of HTML helper classes? Here is your example re-written in MVC:-

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.TicketCurrency,
                            new List<SelectListItem> { 
                                new SelectListItem { Text = "INR", Value = "INR"},
                                new SelectListItem { Text = "USD", Value = "USD"},
                                new SelectListItem { Text = "INR", Value = "EUR"}
                        }, "Select Currency")
```

This will automaticaly select the option whose value is present in `TicketCurrency` property. Also,
I will recommend you to build a type for dropdown in Model and bind it here rather than hard-coding in View.

Answer (score 0):

try like this

//simple drowndown

```
<select class="select" name="TicketCurrency">
                    <option>
                        INR</option>
                    <option>
                        USD</option>
                    <option>
                        EUR</option>
                </select>
```

// then In jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if(ticketDetails != null){
      $('select').val(@ticketDetails.TicketCurrency);
    }
}):
```

Sample demo fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Xxk3F/2019/

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<select class="btn btn-default" data-original-title="" title="" id="@linktxt">
                                        <option value="1" @if (dish.Quantity == 1) { <text> selected="selected" </text>       }>1</option>
                                        <option value="2" @if (dish.Quantity == 2) { <text> selected="selected" </text>       }>2</option>
                                        <option value="3" @if (dish.Quantity == 3) { <text> selected="selected" </text>        }>3</option>
                                        <option value="4" @if (dish.Quantity == 4) { <text> selected="selected" </text>        }>4</option>
                                        <option value="5" @if (dish.Quantity == 5) { <text> selected="selected" </text>        }>5</option>
                                        <option value="6" @if (dish.Quantity == 6) { <text> selected="selected" </text>        }>6</option>
                                        <option value="7" @if (dish.Quantity == 7) { <text> selected="selected" </text>        }>7</option>
                                        <option value="8" @if (dish.Quantity == 8) { <text> selected="selected" </text>        }>8</option>
                                        <option value="9" @if (dish.Quantity == 9) { <text> selected="selected" </text>        }>9</option>
                                        <option value="10" @if (dish.Quantity == 10) { <text> selected="selected" </text>        }>10</option>
                                        <option value="11" @if (dish.Quantity == 11) { <text> selected="selected" </text>        }>11</option>
                                        <option value="12" @if (dish.Quantity == 12) { <text> selected="selected" </text>        }>12</option>
                                        <option value="13" @if (dish.Quantity == 13) { <text> selected="selected" </text>         }>13</option>
                                        <option value="14" @if (dish.Quantity == 14) { <text> selected="selected" </text>         }>14</option>
                                        <option value="15" @if (dish.Quantity == 15) { <text> selected="selected" </text>         }>15</option>
                                        <option value="16" @if (dish.Quantity == 16) { <text> selected="selected" </text>         }>16</option>
                                        <option value="17" @if (dish.Quantity == 17) { <text> selected="selected" </text>         }>17</option>
                                        <option value="18" @if (dish.Quantity == 18) { <text> selected="selected" </text>         }>18</option>
                                        <option value="19" @if (dish.Quantity == 19) { <text> selected="selected" </text>         }>19</option>
                                        <option value="20" @if (dish.Quantity == 20) { <text> selected="selected" </text>         }>20</option>
                                    </select>
```